# Android - Inflate fragment depending on listview item clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

How can I display a string/text inside my `Fragment`, depending on the item clicked in my `ListView`?

This is how my `ListView` looks visually---

[image]

When I click  `Say Hello` I want to display `hello` and when I click `Say Bye` I want to display bye...

[image]
.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.n_Viewpager);
        this.addPages(vp);

    }

    //ADD ALL PAGES
    private void addPages(ViewPager pager) {
        MyFragPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addPage(new ContainerFragment());

        //SET ADAPTER TO PAGER
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

**TestFragment.java**

```
public class TestFragment extends ListFragment {

    //Setting the name of each event
    String[] options = {"Say Hello", "Say Bye"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    //Inflating the view with the fragment
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.listitem, R.id.textview, options);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }

    //Click events
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos, long l) {
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                            getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_root_view, new SaySomethingFragment()).addToBackStack("").commit();

                        break;
                    case 1:

                        break;

                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**ContainerFragment.java**

```
public class ContainerFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container, container, false);
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_root_view, new TestFragment()).commit();
        return view;
    }
}
```

**saysomething_fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/speech_textview"
        android:text="HELLLLOOO"
        android:textSize="40dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a bundle and then set a string to pass as an argument to your fragment.

```
Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
bundle.putString("variable","value");
```

you will need to set the arguments for the fragment

```
.setArguments(bundle);
```

then in your fragment´s onCreate method you can retrieve the data

```
Bundle bundle=getArguments();
String value=bundle.getString("variable");
```

and then you just set the text to your textView

```
Textview textview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView.setText(value);
```

Comment: That was what I ended up doing. Still, thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Move `new SaySomethingFragment()` to a separate variable.

Use the setArguments method of that instance to pass a string extra

Within your Fragment, you can use getArguments() and get that string extra